# What is NET Core 6 analogue of PHP ob_end_flush?

Tags: asp.net-core

PHP programmers can push message to Browser without SignalR, for example https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/main/server-sent-events/sse.php

Is there exist something analog in .NET Core? Or only SignalR can push notification to browser?

Comment: You should know what is [ob_end_flush](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) first.

Comment: There are 3 ways( websocket, longpolling, sse ) to  get the real-time messages, signalr support all of them.

Comment: If you don't want to use signalr, it's ok , you could implement this by yourself, and you still can refer the 3 ways above.

Comment: Thanks, @JasonPan, I 'm forced to use SignalR, but this library looks as trash library, for two last years all methods changed without backward compatibility. And I still don't see any realistic example with push notification without all clients to one concrete loginned client. These are two hard signs of a trash library. Therefore I simple asking - are there more useful push notification libraries in Net Core? Or not? Answer is no, if I have right understanding you.

Comment: And I don't understand why this is very bad and negative question

Comment: SignalR is powerful because after we complete development, if the performance of the web server is not enough, we can quickly migrate the signalr service to azure, which can elastically expand the server-side functions so that more users can establish websocket connections and provide more Reliable service.

Comment: If you face some specific issue, you could add asp.net-core-signalr tag in your post, and we will help u check the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NET Core analogue would be `HttpResponse.WriteAsync` with `HttpResponse.Body.FlushAsync`. For Server Sent Events (SSE) example you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36656174/7775908). Here is some sources from it

### Server Side Alternative #1 - Use Middleware

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path.ToString().Equals("/sse"))
    {
        var response = context.Response;
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");

        for(var i = 0; true; ++i)
        {
            // WriteAsync requires `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http`
            await response
                .WriteAsync($"data: Middleware {i} at {DateTime.Now}\r\r");
                
            await response.Body.FlushAsync();
            await Task.Delay(5 * 1000);
        }
    }

    await next.Invoke();
});
```

### Server Side Alternative #2 - Use a Controller

```cs
[Route("/api/sse")]
public class ServerSentEventController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task Get()
    {
        var response = Response;
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");

        for(var i = 0; true; ++i)
        {
            await response
                .WriteAsync($"data: Controller {i} at {DateTime.Now}\r\r");
                
            response.Body.Flush();
            await Task.Delay(5 * 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like asp.net core signalr. It supports many types of client applications, such as browsers and our desktop applications or services written in many kinds of languages (Java, C#, and so on).

As for the library method changes you mentioned, they are not compatible. It's probably because you were looking at asp.net signalr before. There are currently two versions of signalr, one is asp.net signalr and the other is asp.net core signalr. These two types of signalr have completely different architectures, so they are not compatible, so the methods in the client library will be somewhat different.

I am committed to answering questions about asp.net core signalr, so in short, if you want to use signalr on the front-end page of php, you can choose the matching javascript library according to the type of signalr you use.

Comment: Dear Jason, thank you for your answer, I'm happy that peoples like you is exist at all.  Do you have lint to simple workable example with sending message to only one client from server, not hubContext.Clients, but to only one client. Of couse, more interesting the last version with .NET CORE.

Comment: Hi @Alex , you can find sample code here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75445774/7687666

Comment: Thank, @Jason I use the same pattern, but for many years of using it I can not understand this trask syntax Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", msgType, message); - Why message push to ALL clients? Why not only to concrete one Browser channel? Why is not possible to create normal understandable external interface - Clients. Clent(UnuqieClientID).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", msgType, message) - why this library using Clients.All.SendAsync? Maybe this is main confusion to using SignarR.