# SignalR direct message to single user in angular

Tags: .net, angular, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I am trying to implement direct message to specific user using SignalR(.NET 6) and Angular ~13 and so far I got so many information regarding implementation but none of them work.

So in client side (Angular) I have method to send message

```
export interface IChatMessage {
    id?: number;
    message: string;
    from?: string;
    to?: string;
    created?: Date | null;
}
```

where sending to hub I send only `message` and `to` and `to` is a receiver of that message.
My `chat.service.ts` is

```
export class ChatService {
    private hubConnection: HubConnection;
    private receivedMessageSubject = new Subject<IChatMessage>();
    public connectionId: string;
    receivedMessage$: Observable<IChatMessage> = this.receivedMessageSubject.asObservable();

    constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
        this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(environment.apiUrl + API_ROUTES.CHAT, {accessTokenFactory: () => localStorage.getItem('token')})
            .build();
        this.hubConnection.start().then(() => console.log('connection started')).then(() => this.getConnectionId()).catch((err) => console.error(err));

        this.hubConnection.on('ReceiveMessage', (message) => {
            console.log('Received message from server:', message);
            this.receivedMessageSubject.next(message);
        });
    }

    private getConnectionId = () => {
        this.hubConnection.invoke('getconnectionid')
            .then((data) => {
                this.connectionId = data;
            });
    }

    getMessages(id: string) {
        return this.apiService.post(environment.apiUrl + API_ROUTES.CHAT_MESSAGES, {userId: id});
    }

    sendMessage(message: IChatMessage): void {
        this.hubConnection.invoke('SendMessage', message, this.connectionId)
            .then((response) => console.log('Server response:', response))
            .catch(error => console.error('Error sending message through SignalR:', error));
    }
}
```

On server side I have hub
`ChatHub`

```
        public async Task SendMessage(ChatMessage message, string connectionId)
        {
            try
            {
                var headers = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Headers;
                var user = Context.GetHttpContext().User.Identity;
                Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Context.ConnectionId));
                await Clients.User(connectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error in SendMessage: {ex.Message}");
                throw;
            }
        }
```

and I get the `connectionId` but it's different for each user and cannot map this to connect sender with receiver.
In `Program.cs` I have

```
using IUserIdProvider = Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IUserIdProvider;
...
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, CustomUserIdProvider>();
builder.Services.AddSignalR();

var app = builder.Build();
...
app.UseAuthentication();
...
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/api/chat");
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

and I also have `CustomUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider`

```
    public class CustomUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
    {
        public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
        {
            var uniqueId = connection.User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
            return uniqueId;
        }

    }
```

but `uniqueId` in `CustomUserIdProvider` is empty. For all controllers I have `var user = _userClaims.GetUserId();` which takes `uniqueId` from token from `User` entity which is `string` and is unique. And it works. If I do `await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);` it send message to all users, 'connectionId` is available but only of the sender so receiver does not receive this message. And I have no clue how to implement this in .NET 6 + Angular 13 because like I said I have tried for the last 5 days basically everything that is available in the internet but still no luck. Does anyone have any idea how to implement this so it could be sent in 1-to-1 manner using receiver's uniqueId identyfier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved this.

In `Program.cs` in `AddAuthentication` in `AddJwtBearer` (because authentication is with JWT) I added

```
    config.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
            var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && (path.StartsWithSegments("/api/chat")))
            {
                context.Token = accessToken;
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
```

next added `builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, CustomUserIdProvider>();` and after `Useauthorization` I added

```
var idProvider = new CustomUserIdProvider();
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => idProvider);
```

I have also created `CustomUserIdPrvider`

```
    public class CustomUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
    {
        public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
        {
            var uniqueId = connection.User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
            return uniqueId;
        }

    }
```

and `SendMessage in` ChatHub`

```
        public async Task SendMessage(ChatMessage message)
        {
            var httpContext = Context.GetHttpContext();
            var user = httpContext.User.Claims.Where(user => user.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
            var token = httpContext.Request.Query["access_token"];
            message.From = user;
            message.Created = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
            await Clients.Users(message.To, user).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
        }
```

so with
`Clients.Users(message.To, user)` I am able to send message content to specific user with uniqueId (NOT! connectionId!)

Answer (score 0):

When a user (`browser` or `other devices`) connect to the Hub endpoint, the generated `connectionId` is randomly generated by `signalr` itself, if the application stop/crash, the `connectionIds` will be disappeared, we can't use it any more.

A user has only one uniqueId, but he can open many web pages and use multiple mobile devices with colleagues, so we need to maintain the relationship between them ourselves. For more details, [you can check my answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75423096/7687666).

**Here is the sample I am using for test.**

```
namespace SignalRMiddleawre.Hubs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    [Authorize]
    public partial class MainHub : Hub
    {
        #region Connection
        /// <summary>
        /// Manage Connected Users
        /// </summary>
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<string?, List<string>>? ConnectedUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string?, List<string>>();
        /// <summary>
        /// OnConnect Event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userid"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        ///
        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            // Get HttpContext In asp.net core signalr
            //IHttpContextFeature hcf = (IHttpContextFeature)this.Context.Features[typeof(IHttpContextFeature)];
            //HttpContext hc = hcf.HttpContext;
            //string uid = hc.Request.Path.Value.Split(new string[] { "=", "" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1].ToString();

            string? userid = Context.User?.Identity?.Name;
            if (userid == null || userid.Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation("user not loged in, can't connect signalr service");
                return;
            }
            Trace.TraceInformation(userid + "connected");
            // save connection
            List<string>? existUserConnectionIds;
            ConnectedUsers.TryGetValue(userid, out existUserConnectionIds);
            if (existUserConnectionIds == null)
            {
                existUserConnectionIds = new List<string>();
            }
            existUserConnectionIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
            ConnectedUsers.TryAdd(userid, existUserConnectionIds);

            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ServerInfo", userid, userid + " connected, connectionId = " + Context.ConnectionId);
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// OnDisconnected event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userid"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
        {
            string? userid = Context.User?.Identity?.Name;
            // save connection
            List<string>? existUserConnectionIds;
            ConnectedUsers.TryGetValue(userid, out existUserConnectionIds);

            existUserConnectionIds.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);

            if (existUserConnectionIds.Count == 0)
            {
                List<string> garbage;
                ConnectedUsers.TryRemove(userid, out garbage);
            }

            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Message
        /// <summary>
        /// Send msg to all user
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userid"></param>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task SendMessage(string msgType, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", msgType, message);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Send msg to user by userid
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connectionId"></param>
        /// <param name="message">message format : type-message </param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task SendToSingleUser(string userid, string message)
        {
            List<string>? existUserConnectionIds;
            // find all the connectionids by userid
            ConnectedUsers.TryGetValue(userid, out existUserConnectionIds);
            if (existUserConnectionIds == null)
            {
                existUserConnectionIds = new List<string>();
            }
            existUserConnectionIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
            ConnectedUsers.TryAdd(userid, existUserConnectionIds);
            await Clients.Clients(existUserConnectionIds).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```